# Fonts not properly embedded in generated PDF using itextsharp 5.0.5.0

Tags: itext

I am trying to generate PDF using itextsharp api for "Gujarati font" using below code.

BaseFont gujarati = BaseFont.CreateFont("D\Gujarati\shruti.ttf", BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
            Font fontNormal = new Font(gujarati, 10, Font.NORMAL);

PDF getting generated but fonts are not properly displayed. if i am convert same PDF to word then fonts are correctly displayed.

Comment: You'll need itext7 with the caligraph add-on to support Indic scripts. It won't work with itext5.

Comment: In addition to what @Paulo said: even if you need to try something using itext 5, the version 5.0.5.0 is ancient, the current 5.5.x versions are improved in many ways.

Comment: I have upgraded itext5 to itext 7.1.x but still issues is not resolved. same as itext5 output displayed.

Document arabicPdf = new Document(new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter("D:\\test.pdf")));
        string ARIALUNI_TFF = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Fonts), "shruti.ttf");
        PdfFont f = PdfFontFactory.CreateFont("D:\\Gujarati\\New folder\\shruti.ttf", PdfEncodings.IDENTITY_H, true);
        arabicPdf.SetFont(f);
        arabicPdf.Add(new Paragraph("iText is: નમસ્તે ગતિના").SetFont(f));
        arabicPdf.Close();

Answer (score 0):

This post details how to load `pdfCalligraph`, use the right font (since the font must be capable of displaying the characters), and adding them to a `PdfDocument`

First you need to ensure `pdfCalligraph` is on your classpath.
If you are using Maven, simply add the dependency.

https://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-jump-start-tutorial/installing-itext-7

Second, you need to load a valid license. `pdfCalligraph` is a closed-source add-on to the `iText` platform. So a license is needed.

https://developers.itextpdf.com/content/license-key-frequently-asked-questions/how-do-i-load-license-key

Next, the following code-sample ought to do it.

```
Document arabicPdf = new Document(new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter("/path/to/arabic.pdf")));

// Arabic text starts near the top right corner of the page
arabicPdf.setTextAlignment(TextAlignment.RIGHT);

// create a font, and make it the default for the document
PdfFont f = PdfFontFactory.createFont("/path/to/DroidKufi-Regular.ttf", PdfEncodings.IDENTITY_H, true);
arabicPdf.setFont(f);

// add content: السلام عليكم (as-salaamu 'aleykum - peace be upon you)
arabicPdf.add(new Paragraph("\u0627\u0644\u0633\u0644\u0627\u0645 \u0639\u0644\u064A\u0643\u0645"));

arabicPdf.close();
```

It was copied verbatim from the `iText` website.
https://itextpdf.com/itext7/pdfcalligraph